# Use ZXing libs to decode bitmap with a QRCode on Android

Tags: java, android, zxing

Recently I have a difficulty using zxing to decode bitmap. I search solutions on Internet and I have tried some of them.Here is my try:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.qrcode);
    String result = DecodeUtils.decodeWithZxing(bitmap);
```

`R.drawable.qrcode`   is a `.jpg` file.

And `BarCodeUtil.java` is:

```
 public static String decodeWithZxing(Bitmap bitmap) {
    MultiFormatReader multiFormatReader = new MultiFormatReader();
    Map<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<>();
    hints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);
    multiFormatReader.setHints(hints);

    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    Result rawResult = null;
    RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, pixels);

    if (source != null) {
        BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        try {
            rawResult = multiFormatReader.decodeWithState(binaryBitmap);
        } catch (ReaderException re) {
            re.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            multiFormatReader.reset();
        }
    }
    return rawResult != null ? rawResult.getText() : null;
}
```

But when I run the above code,I got a exception:

> com.google.zxing.NotFoundException

So I search the exception,someone think bitmap size causes this exception.Then I resize the bitmap size:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = 4; 
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.zhifubao,options);
    String result = DecodeUtils.decodeWithZxing(bitmap)
```

But it still does not work for me.

Is there a good solution to decode bitmap with a qrcode?

Comment: How did you add the library to your project?

Comment: I add **zxing-4.7.3.jar** as a library @Eenvincible

Comment: Did you also Right-Click it and selected Add as a Library ?

Comment: @Eenvincible If I have not added it as a library,I would get some error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably very late, but, that just means that no barcode was found in the image. See [here](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/)

> **NotFoundException**
>   Thrown when a barcode was not found in the image.

If anyone else ends up with the same problem, that is, cannot decode a barcode such as QRcode or upc, a possibility might be using the wrong colorspace of the bitmap. You might be attempting to use RGB when the data from the camera is actually in YUV.

Instead of RGBLuminanceSource, you should use PlanarYUVLuminanceSource as in the example [here](https://github.com/RuanXiaoHui/ZxingScan/blob/master/ZxingScan/zxinglib/src/main/java/cn/jackson/zxinglib/decoding/DecodeHandler.java)

Answer (score -2):

your development tools is eclipse  or  android studio ？

if is android stuido:

in your project > app > build. gradel  on add:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

}

then sync gradle.

Comment: If the library isn't added into the project,I will get error